# how to make sqlite query more efficent?

Tags: sqlite

I have the follow sql statement in a program I am building, where id_list is sometimes a very large list.

```
for id in id_list:
    self.cursor.execute("""update songs set rating='L' where trackid=?""", (id,))
self.db.commit()
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this that doesn't involve so many update queries?

Comment: +1 for thinking about your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL:

```
update songs set rating='L' where trackid IN (id_list)
```

Code:

```
self.cursor.execute("update songs set rating='L' where trackid IN (%s)"%','.join(['?']*len(id_list)), id_list)
self.db.commit()
```

There is also more elegant, but suboptimal solution:

```
self.cursor.executemany("update songs set rating='L' where trackid=?", id_list)
self.db.commit()
```

Comment: The second options appears to be the same as the original poster has.

Comment: Thanks, I used your 1st solution and everything works as it should.